# Java OOP перебор Map

Tags: java, ооп, map

Есть сущность Сar и Map в которой хранится экземпляры.
При поиске Car по модели и диллеру - ничего не выводит.
При поиске Сar по скорости больше заданной выдает не корректные данные (к примеру казанно 100 минимум а выдает обьекты где поле скорость 3)

```
public void  GetByModel(String model) {
    System.out.println("By model: ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Car> item : car.entrySet()){
    if (item.getValue().getModel()==model) {
        System.out.println(
                "Id: "+item.getKey()+" Model: "+car.get(id).getModel()+
                " Dealer: "+car.get(id).getDealer()+" Speed: "+car.get(id).getSpeed()+"\n");
    }
    }
}
@Override
public void  GetByDealer(String dealer) {
    System.out.println("By dealer: ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Car> item : car.entrySet()){
        if (item.getValue().getDealer()==dealer) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Id: "+item.getKey()+" Model: "+car.get(id).getModel()+
                    " Dealer: "+car.get(id).getDealer()+" Speed: "+car.get(id).getSpeed()+"\n");
        }
        }
}
@Override
public void  GetByMaxSpeedLimit(double speed) {
    System.out.println("By speed min: ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Car> item : car.entrySet()){
        if (item.getValue().getSpeed()>=speed) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Id: "+item.getKey()+" Model: "+car.get(id).getModel()+
                    " Dealer: "+car.get(id).getDealer()+" Speed: "+car.get(id).getSpeed()+"\n");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1) Строки в java сравнивайте через equals

Comment: @tym32167 огромное спасибо!

Comment: 2) Со скоростью вы что то сами намудрили, код выглядит ок

Comment: 3) вы используете HashMap как простой список. Вам точно нужен HashMap?

Comment: @tym32167 со скоростью разобрался. Касательно Мап: когда я использовал ЭрейЛист у меня возникли проблемы со сравнением id на предмет уникальности. Мап эту проблему решил благодаря containsKey()

Comment: Тогда вам лучше переопределить методы equals и hashCode класса Car, если ещё не сделали это, и использовать HashSet.